# Using QCryptographicHash in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, cryptography

I have a string that I write and read inside the text file. I want to encrypt this strig. Do I have to use the QCryptographicHash library for this? If I need to use QCryptographicHash can you give me an example of that?

Comment: Related: [2990722](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2990722/16586783), [5495281](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5495281/16586783)

Answer (score 0):

`QCryptographicHash` is not able to encrypt your data. Actually, this class is made to compute a hash from your data, which can be seen as a descriptor of your data.

You can find more [details here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

To encrypt/decrypt your data, you will need to find an external library which handles it (Crypto++, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You should use QCA which is Qt Cryptographic Architecture.
In Ubuntu/Debian based Linux you can get it using

```
sudo apt install libqca-qt5-2 libqca-qt5-2-dev libqca-qt5-2-plugins
```

[Here](https://api.kde.org/qca/html/examples.html) is a bunch of examples.

Answer (score 0):

To encrypt data in qt you should use an external library.[AES and SHA](https://github.com/jparker2006/EncryptedStorage/tree/main/desktop%20app/main/crypto). Look into that repo if you need examples for how to use those libraries.